# Doctrine : MappingException: The target-entity CLASS cannot be found in

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I do not understand a thing...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: The
>   target-entity Shop cannot be found in 'User#shops'. in

I just have a `User` class.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 **/
class User
{

    /** @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Shop", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $shops;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->shops = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Who has multiple `Shop`s.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Shop
{

    /** @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="shops")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

They are in the same directory, so it is not a `namespace` issue isn't it ?

Getters & Setters has been generated has well, but still does not change a thing.

**TIPS** : If a put all my classes in the same php file, it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided these are the full files, you are not writing any `namespace` declarations on the classes. Therefore the Entity classes are put in the `\` root namespace.

So to resolve this you will either need to use the FQN (Full Qualified Name) or import the classes.

#### Using FQN (my recommendation)

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Shop", mappedBy="user")
 */
```

*(add the same in the other class as well)*

#### Using import

Add this on the top of the User class

```
use \Shop;
```

*(the inverse in the other class of course)*

Note: The PHP Interpreter doesn't check for usages in Annotations, so if you don't use the class elsewhere in the file, PHP might show a warning about an unused import if that is enabled.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it is good now !

But the `use \Shop;` is not valid, I had to remove it to make things work, PHP said :


`Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Shop' has no effect in /.../app/model/src/User.php on line 3`

Comment: @Dinath That's because the PHP Interpreter doesn't check for usages in Annotations. Technically it would work but in this use-case my recommendation is cleaner. Anyhow, once you're able to, I'd apprecciate it if you'd accept my answer